# Why is circletype.js jquery not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Can someone please help me work out why this is not working??

I have checked and triple checked that the js files are linked correctly.

Am I missing something really obvious? This is exactly how they said to use it! :(

What I am trying to use :

http://circletype.labwire.ca/

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Heroes and Villians</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ma.css">
 <script src="modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>

  </head>
 <body>


<h2 id="title1">Heroes</h2>



<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script src="circletype.min.js"></script>

<script>


$('#title1').circleType({radius:384});
</script>

    </body>
 </html>
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lettering.js is missing so please link this script http://circletype.labwire.ca/js/plugins.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Heroes and Villians</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ma.css">
 <script src="modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>

  </head>
 <body>


<h2 id="title1">Heroes</h2>



<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script src="circletype.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://circletype.labwire.ca/js/plugins.js"></script>

<script>


$('#title1').circleType({radius:384});
</script>

    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I was following a tutorial on how to use it and it never mentioned this extra script at all! Thanks you're a life saver

Comment: i've upvoted (it won't show because i'm a new user) , and I accepted your answer.

Comment: It does not work :(